# How to setup TeXnicCenter for compiling SageTeX-based input files?

Tags: windows, texniccenter, sagetex

Having found the solution through a dramatic struggle, I think I need to rephrase the question. Hopefully it is very useful for others with the same issue, nameely:

*"How to setup TeXnicCenter for compiling SageTeX-based input files?"*

Assume that we have an MWE taken from SageTeX's official site as follows

```
% test.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

Using Sage\TeX, one can use Sage to compute things and put them into
your \LaTeX{} document. For example, there are
$\sage{number_of_partitions(1269)}$ integer partitions of $1269$.
You don't need to compute the number yourself, or even cut and paste
it from somewhere.

Here's some Sage code:

\begin{sageblock}
    f(x) = exp(x) * sin(2*x)
\end{sageblock}

The second derivative of $f$ is

\[
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} \sage{f(x)} =
  \sage{diff(f, x, 2)(x)}.
\]

Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:

\sageplot{plot(f, -1, 1)}

\end{document}
```

we want to compile it with TeXnicCenter (of course only on WINDOWS) as convenient as possible. How to do so?

Comment: The global environment should be named `PATH`, but it is possible that Windows can't tell the difference. This doesn't look like a TeX-related question, though, since the problem appears to be “I can't run `sage.exe`.”

Comment: Not sure how it could “converge” this way, but certainly giving the precise error message would help converge towards an understanding of the problem.

Comment: Is there really a `sage.exe` in the directory you added to the `PATH`? This sounds strange. What if you use an explicit path? As in `"C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.0\runtime\bin\sage" test.sagetex.sage`.

Comment: Well, no surprise then. You need to install Sage.

Comment: It must be somewhere. I don't use Windows, but on my Linux computer, `sage` is a Bash script. Maybe you need to look for an extension that is  different from `.exe`.

Comment: This seems to be the object of [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/issues/35).

Comment: Possibly, but you can test it while I can't. :-)

Comment: @frougon: I have found the solution. It is time to play with `sagetex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Installation

1. Install TeXnicCenter.
2. Install Sage. SageTeX is included in Sage installation.
3. Install TeXLive.
4. Install Adobe Acrobat.

## Make SageTeX known to TeX

- We have to copy the folder `sagetex` from `C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.0\runtime\opt\sagemath-9.0\local\share\texmf\tex\latex\` and paste it to `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local\`.
- Next type `texhash` on the command prompt and enter to invoke it.

This procedure makes `sagetex.sty` package known to the installed TeXLive.

## Configuring `PATH`

Configuring `PATH` with a batch file is preferred if you need to do this procedure multiple times in the future with minimal edits. Here is the batch file.

```
REM ConfigurePath.bat

PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.0\runtime\bin
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.0\runtime\opt\sagemath-9.0
setx PATH "%PATH%" /m
```

Invoke the batch with **administrative privilege**.

## Configuring TeXnicCenter

Even though TeXnicCenter provides us with prebuild and postbuild events to control the building process, using them is not as convenient as using a batch file below.

```
rem SageTeX.bat
echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension
rem %2 current directory

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex  -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"     

rem set the current directory for sagetex to work properly
@set HOME=%~dp2       

if exist "%~1.sagetex.sage" bash -l sage "%~1.sagetex.sage"

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex  "%~1.tex"

for %%x in (aux log sagetex.sage sagetex.sage.py sagetex.scmd sagetex.sout) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")    

if exist ".ccache" rmdir /s /q ".ccache"
if exist ".sage" rmdir /s /q ".sage"
if exist "sage-plots-for-%~1.tex" rmdir /s /q "sage-plots-for-%~1.tex"
```

The batch looks complicated because I added housekeeping routines (to remove unnecessary files and directories) to it.

Create a new output profile in TeXnicCenter. The settings are given as follows.

[image]

Note: The trailing `\` in `%dm\` is not trivial!

Finish!